# Convert Google Maps image to ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, georeferencing

I would like to import a Google Maps image of **Costa Rica** into ArcMap and create a shapefile of this region. A screenshot of the selected region has been taken and I want to process it into ArcMap and create a shapefile from it.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are okay with using the screenshot, the steps that you have to follow are:

1. Use the concept of georeferencing in ArcMap. For accurate georeferencing, you need reference data/ control points. But in your case, you can use the ESRI default basemap(imagery/topography) to align your screenshot by marking down some known locations/spots(streets intersections, lakes boundaries, etc).
2. Once the screenshot is brought to its exact location, go ahead with creating a new file geodatabase with whatever features(points, lines, and polygons) you would like to create/extract.

**Tips:**

- Use bookmarks in ArcMap to the first markdown the known locations in
  the ESRI basemap to toggle easily
- While georeferencing make sure you stop adding control points when
  the image is aligned correctly it can take 2 points or 20 points
  depending on your points selection
- Use a clockwise method for adding control points

If you are confused about what I am talking about try to first go through the below documents:

- https://dsc.gmu.edu/files/Georeferencing-and-Digitizing-in-ArcGIS.pdf
- https://mdl.library.utoronto.ca/technology/tutorials/how-georeference-images-arcgis
- https://youtu.be/PHtxbpboDro
- https://geospatialhistorian.wordpress.com/lessons/arcgis-lesson-3-georeferencing-maps/
- https://gpshort.uga.edu/instructions/gis/Georeference%20an%20image%20using%20ArcMap.pdf
- https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/georeferencing-toolbar-tools.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with data that is not spatially located, you must first georeference it. There is also a tool for this. Then you could create a new shapefile layer and "trace" the relevant data in edit mode.

It is probably much easier to simply download the data you need, for example from [osm](https://export.hotosm.org/de/v3/) (vector data) or [google earth enginge](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting) (raster data).

Comment: Actually, I want to create a simple map of the study location. A shapefile for the county (the place of my study area) is not available. Therefore, I need to create a shapefile using an image from Google Maps.

Comment: @soph, absolutely correct, we have an entire toolbar dedicated to georeferencing in ArcMap. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/georeferencing-toolbar-tools.htm